# Setting maintenance mode via REST API

Tags: rest-api, maintenance

Is there a way to set a WP site to maintenance mode via REST API?

Comment: Did you check the official [reference for existing endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/)? Or are you asking how to implement something like this?

Comment: Thanks, I did check it, couldn't find any endpoint that supports this operation (given that I correctly understood the endpoints).
Wanted to know if someone knows how to implement this or if there is any plug-in that supports that.

Comment: Plugin questions are off topic here, sorry. As for implementation: This can probably be done, the linked documentation also describes how to implement custom endpoints. What you'll have to check though, is the REST API even available when in maintenance? Otherwise, you can never turn it off.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will follow up there. I assume that taking the site out of maintenance can be done via UI.

Comment: If you mean the default WP maintenance, no you cannot use the UI. You need file access (usually FTP) to remove the _.maintenance_. If you've been talking about the maintenance mode of a plugin, you should ask their support. (Usually via the wordpress.org > plugin > support possible.)

Comment: Thanks! Would moving the maintenance mode with this code keep UI access? https://websitesetup.org/wordpress-into-maintenance-mode/

Comment: There are many versions described in that article. You should start by formulating your requirements and then go search for a plugin that supports this. None of this really fits this Q&A stack here, sorry.